# Understanding hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer property in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

As per the Hibernate Documentation, hibernate has a property called `hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer` and the doc says:

> Enables the use of bytecode manipulation instead of runtime
>   reflection. This is a System-level property and cannot be set in
>   hibernate.cfg.xml. Reflection can sometimes be useful when
>   troubleshooting. Hibernate always requires javassist even if you turn
>   off the optimizer.
>
> e.g. true | false

What is byte code manipulation and runtime reflection and how hibernate uses it. Can someone please help m in understanding this. Also how reflection is useful for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2):

That's a bit too much for one question. Also the required level of detail to sufficiently answer the last part of your problem would probably be too advanced given the fact that the rest of your question is rather basic.

> What is byte code manipulation and runtime reflection?

If you've never heard about **byte** **code** **manipulation** & **reflection** before I suggest you start exploring it yourself, utilizing the search engine of your choice. If you have any concrete question about either topic you are more than welcome to post it here at SOF.

> how hibernate uses it

For the second part of your question I suggest looking at the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html) and e.g. highlight the usage of "bytecode". This should give you a basic understanding of where it's being used. Again, get back to SOF with any concrete question.

> Also how reflection is useful for troubleshooting

In a nutshell: Because you can use your IDE to debug and e.g. inspect variables - something you cannot do if the IDE sits on top of modified bytecode. At least not easily. But this should hopefully be much clearer after your own research.

Comment: Searching "hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" lead me to this question. It's is (at least right now) the top result on google and bing.

Comment: That has always been my plan for 2021 when I answered the question in 2014.